# How can I use shared logic from different files?

Tags: rust

Having shared logic in:

```rust
// euler/shared/lib.rs

pub fn foo() {
    println!("shared::foo()");
}
```

How can I use it from different files:

```rust
// euler/001/main.rs

use super::shared; // error: unresolved import `super::shared`

fn main() {
  shared::foo(); // how to access it?
}
```

```rust
// euler/002/main.rs

use super::shared; // error: unresolved import `super::shared`

fn main() {
  shared::foo(); // how to access it?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mdup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30286981/155423) is correct, but I'd encourage you to use Cargo, Rust's package manager. It will do two very important things for you here:

1. Set up the correct command line arguments to `rustc`.
2. Automatically rebuild the dependent libraries when they change.

Use `cargo new shared` and `cargo new --bin euler-001` to generate the right directory structure. Move your shared code to `shared/src/lib.rs` and your binaries to `euler-001/src/main.rs`:

```
.
├── euler-001
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── shared
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

Then, edit `euler-001/Cargo.toml` and add the dependencies section:

```
[dependencies.shared]
path = "../shared"
```

And tweak your `main.rs` to know about the crate:

```
extern crate shared;

fn main() {
    shared::foo();
}
```

Now, you can simply type `cargo run` in the `euler-001` directory:

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling shared v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/play/euler-001)
   Compiling euler-001 v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/play/euler-001)
     Running `target/debug/euler-001`
shared::foo()
```

Note that you don't have to remember command line arguments and things are compiled for you! Having a built-in package manager is great!

Comment: Indeed both the cargo approach and the manual link approach are correct, they all have their use cases! Manual linking is great for a one-off program (like Project Euler exercises), but when you first need to install a package you'll be glad to have invested in the cargo structure. +1

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to create a library out of the shared code. This will allow you to use an `extern crate` declaration.

```
// euler/shared/shared.rs
pub fn foo() {
    println!("shared::foo()");
}
```

To compile the lib:

```
$ cd euler/shared
$ rustc --crate-type=lib shared.rs
$ ls -l libshared.rlib                                                                                                
-rw-r--r--  1 mdup  wheel  6758 May 17 14:38 libshared.rlib
```

Here is how you use it in "client" code:

```
// euler/001/main.rs

extern crate shared;

fn main() {
  shared::foo();
}
```

The compile the client:

```
$ cd euler/001
$ rustc -L ../shared main.rs
$ ls -l main
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mdup  wheel  291420 May 17 14:42 main
$ ./main
shared::foo()
```

More info in [Rust By Example](http://rustbyexample.com), section "Crates", pages ["Library"](http://rustbyexample.com/crates/lib.html) and ["extern crate"](http://rustbyexample.com/crates/link.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I really like it. I'm marking @Shepmaster's answer because it's the recommended solution to this problem. It's better to highlight it for people who are looking for solution to this problem. Thank you.