# Creating a Rust library with multiple modules which all are a unified API

Tags: module, rust, rust-crates

I have an exercise library to learn Rust. This library provides two kinds of methods:

1. *core* methods which should be in a file called **renderay_core.rs**.
2. *shape* methods which *use* the core methods to have a higher abstraction/more concrete implementation of the core methods; convenience methods for "often used" cases. These should be in a file called **renderay_shapes.rs**.

I also want to have unit tests in them as submodules.

I thought of something like:

- **renderay.rs** is the library source `[lib] path="src/renderay.rs"`
- **renderay_core.rs** is a module which is loaded into **renderay.rs** as public(?) to yield its API
- **renderay_shapes.rs** is also a module within **renderay.rs** but also imports **renderay_core.rs** to its core API

If I load this crate as a dependency, I would like to have the API of **renderay_core.rs** and **renderay_shapes.rs** available.

I'm sure it is a trivial task, but I have a hard time getting my head around the module mechanics coming from Java and C. I already read the [crates and modules documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html). How to setup such a structure and compile it successfully?

Comment: Why do you care what the file names are? Why not just `src/lib.rs`, `src/core.rs` and `src/shapes.rs`; the crate is called *renderay*, and the modules would be at `renderay::core`?

Comment: And what about shapes.rs ? how should I import core? use renderay::core ?

Comment: [How do I import from a sibling module?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30677258/155423); [How do you use parent module imports in rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20922091/155423); [Split implementation across multiple files/modules and keep everything as private as possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36021619/155423); [How can I use shared logic from different files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30286861/155423).

Comment: thank you - didn't had the right keywords for those results!